# How to stop raycast when hitting an object in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

In my Unity game (top-down 2D shooter) there are some enemies flying along a path (via DOTween). My player casts a ray into the scene in order to get an enemy-object right in front of the player. So far so good.

Now the problem is that I want only one enemy-object as a result, i.e. the raycast should stop when it hits an enemy-object for the very first time. How do I achieve this?

I need only one enemy-object hit by the raycast because there is a crosshair in my game and when the raycast starts and the enemies fly along the path the crosshair jumps forth and back (and I don't want this - the crosshair should stay at the first enemy hit by the raycast).

[Raycast video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGZ5d.jpg)

This is my code (attached to the player):

```
void FixedUpdate() {
    
    //crosshair: Cast a ray straight up.
    float _size = 12f;
        Vector2 _direction = this.transform.up;
        RaycastHit2D _hit = Physics2D.Raycast(this.transform.position, _direction, _size);

    if (_hit.collider != null && _hit.collider.tag == "EnemyShipTag") {

        // We touched something!

        Vector2 target = new Vector2(_hit.collider.gameObject.transform.position.x, _hit.collider.gameObject.transform.position.y);

        const float moveTime = 0.1f;
        float step;

        step = Vector2.Distance(crosshairGO.transform.position, target);
        crosshairGO.transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(crosshairGO.transform.position, target, step / moveTime * Time.deltaTime);

        Vector2 _pos3 = new Vector2(this.transform.position.x, crosshairGO.transform.position.y);
        crosshairGO.transform.position = _pos3;
        crosshairBegin = false;
    } else {
        // Nothing hit

        Vector2 _pos2 = new Vector2(this.transform.position.x, 4.5f);
        if (crosshairBegin) {
            crosshairGO.transform.position = _pos2;
        } else {
            Vector2 _pos4 = new Vector2(this.transform.position.x, crosshairGO.transform.position.y);
            crosshairGO.transform.position = _pos4;
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Check out this [Unity forum answer](https://answers.unity.com/questions/384355/stopping-a-raycast-after-hit.html).

Comment: Yeah I know this thread but I can't get it working in my case. I use the following code-snippet in my code: RaycastHit hitPoint;
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(this.transform.position); 
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hitPoint, Mathf.Infinity)) {
            if (hitPoint.collider.tag == "EnemyShipTag") {
                Debug.Log("Enemy object hit"); 
            }
         
        } else {
             Debug.Log ("No collider hit"); 
        } The code doesn't work in my case. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you certain it is hitting multiple enemies? Or just the same enemy every frame? If you want it to only print when it hits an enemy for the first time that is different.

Comment: I understood my problem now. There are gaps in my enemy-path so the ray casts through the gaps and hits the back row. That's the reason why they jump forth and back.

Comment: Glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you right. You could create a bool value and set it true after you hit something.

For example:

```
Vector2 _pos3 = new Vector2(this.transform.position.x, crosshairGO.transform.position.y);
    crosshairGO.transform.position = _pos3;
    crosshairBegin = false;
    youHitSomething = true;
```

Before you create the ray
you could write an if

```
if(!youHitSomething)
{
    float _size = 12f;
    Vector2 _direction = this.transform.up;
    RaycastHit2D _hit = Physics2D.Raycast(this.transform.position, _direction, _size);

     if (_hit.collider != null && _hit.collider.tag == "EnemyShipTag") 
     {
        // We touched something!
        // your Code 
        youHitSomething = true; 
     } 
     else 
    {
    // Nothing hit
    // your code
    }   
}
```

To let the ray cast again you could create a new method

```
public void ActivateRay()
{
   youHitSomething = false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! I will check this out ASAP!:)